# Accessing Excels using qtp

Tags: vbscript, qtp

While trying to save Excel using qtp, I am getting error "File couldn't be accessed. Try one of the following".

Everything is correct but still I am getting error. Here is my code:

```
Dim objExcel
set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
objExcel.visible = true  objExcel.Workbooks.Add 
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.saveAs "‪D:\UFT Practice Scripts\UFT.xlsx"
objExcel = nothing
```

Comment: I suggest trying to run this as a standalone vbscript to determine if QTP has anything to do with it.

Comment: I tried running with alone vbcript but still same error.

Comment: It worked now :)

Comment: @RoshanJha If you have fixed it, you can post it as answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the row **`objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False`** works for me..

```
Dim objExcel
set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.visible = true
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "D:\uft.xlsx"
objExcel = nothing
```